# Apply ifelse() to multiple columns with dynamic contingency on another column

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set that contains `NAs`. I want to fill these values with values contingent on another, secondary column. However, this secondary column is dynamic and changes depending on the primary column.

To illustrate, I want to replicate the following process:

```
l1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A")
l2 <- c(NA, "B", "B", "B")
l3 <- c(NA, NA, "C", "C")
l4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "D")

prodmap <- data.frame(l1, l2, l3, l4)

prodmap[] <- lapply(prodmap, as.character) 

prodmap$l2 <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap$l2), prodmap$l1, prodmap$l2)
prodmap$l3 <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap$l3), prodmap$l2, prodmap$l3)
prodmap$l4 <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap$l4), prodmap$l3, prodmap$l4)
```

How can I do this? Especially, the columns should be dynamically called by their names, without requiring manual specification, as I did above. I believe loops could be an option, but so far I was not able to figure out how to deal with the challenge of dynamically changing column names.

Comment: Try `for(i in 2:4) prodmap[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap[[i]]), prodmap[[i-1]], prodmap[[i]])`

Comment: Thanks! But I believe this would call the columns via index, correct? I am rather looking for a way to dynamically address columns by name.

Comment: That is easier, but if you want to pass column names, that is possible as well

Comment: `nm1 <- names(prodmap)[-1]; nm2 <- names(prodmap)[-ncol(prodmap)]; for(i in seq_along(nm1)) prodmap[[nm1[i]]] <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap[[nm1[i]]], prodmap[[nm2[i]]], prodmap[[nm1[i]]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the next column depends on the previous one, we can use a `for` loop with index to do this

```
for(i in 2:ncol(prodmap)) prodmap[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap[[i]]), 
              prodmap[[i-1]], prodmap[[i]])
prodmap
#  l1 l2 l3 l4
#1  A  A  A  A
#2  A  B  B  B
#3  A  B  C  C
#4  A  B  C  D
```

---

If we want to use column names instead of column index, create two `vector`s of column names, removing the first and last column name ('nm1', 'nm2'), loop through the sequence of the `vector`, extract the corresponding column name based on index and update the column of 'prodmap'

```
nm1 <- tail(names(prodmap), -1)
nm2 <- head(names(prodmap), -1)
for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
  prodmap[[nm1[i]]] <- ifelse(is.na(prodmap[[nm1[i]]]), 
                               prodmap[[nm2[i]]],
                               prodmap[[nm1[i]]])
   }
```

NOTE: Assuming that the NAs can be distributed anywhere in the column

Answer (score 1):

An option using `upper.tri`

```
prodmap[upper.tri(prodmap)] <- t(prodmap)[upper.tri(prodmap)]
prodmap
#  l1 l2 l3 l4
#1  A  A  A  A
#2  A  B  B  B
#3  A  B  C  C
#4  A  B  C  D
```

The idea is to fill the missing values which are all found in `prodmap[upper.tri(prodmap)]` with the values we get when we first transpose `prodmap` then extract the values from the resulting matrix that are found in the upper triangle.